# Typescript error concerning maps: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
export const MyComponent = <
  T extends { id?: string; iterator: string }
>({
  data,
   iterator
}: Props<T>) => (
  <div>
      {data?.map((i: T) => (
        <MySecondComp key={i.id}  text={i[iterator]} />
      ))}
  </div>
)
```

but it's complaining on the `i[iterator]` part with the title of this question

how do I solve this? essentially I'm mapping over data and have made it reusable and you can pass in an iterator and the data is unknown

Comment: what are the types for props to `<MySecondComp key={i.id}  text={i[iterator]} />`?

Comment: just both strings

Comment: the second one gives me an error saying: can't be used to index type 'unknown'.

Comment: `T extends { id?: string; iterator: keyof T}` So, what I'm trying to do is let typescript know that iterator is a key of instance i which is of type T.

Comment: I'm not sure I want the extends stuff. I originally had `<T, >`